# Replacing Multiple Characters Excel / AirTable

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm looking to replace multiple instances of characters in an AirTable spreadsheet which for the most part uses/[can be adapted](https://support.airtable.com/hc/en-us/articles/203255215-Formula-field-reference) from Excel formulas. I'm trying to create a field which creates the [phonetic NATO version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_phonetic_alphabet) of an order number from a given field `A`. For example, if `A` is `S33BSAT`, the formula would output `Sierra-33-Bravo-Sierra-Alfa-Tango`. Would appreciate your ideas for the cleanest way to implement locally.

Comment: You should edit your post and add a sample data. Do the characters in column A always follow the same pattern?

Comment: Could you provide the sample about your requirement?

Comment: Column A contains order IDs from different vendors so they can contain alphanumeric symbols of any length/in any order.

Answer (score 0):

If the characters always follow the same pattern, then you can use a lookup table and another column to display the result Then use the formula below to extract the extract the code and build the text. In my example, the lookup table is in column D and the search data in column F and the results in column H.

```
=IF(F5<>"",INDEX(D:D,XMATCH(MID(F5,1,1) & "?",$D$1:$D$26,1)) & "-" & MID(F5,2,2) & "-" & INDEX(D:D,XMATCH(MID(F5,4,1) & "?",$D$1:$D$26,1)) & "-" & INDEX(D:D,XMATCH(MID(F5,5,1) & "?",$D$1:$D$26,1)) & "-" & INDEX(D:D,XMATCH(MID(F5,6,1) & "?",$D$1:$D$26,1)) & "-" & INDEX(D:D,XMATCH(MID(F5,7,1) & "?",$D$1:$D$26,1)),"")
```

[image: IMG:]